# where to locate user config file for java app on windows?

Tags: java, windows, configuration, standards

i'm creating a java library mylib that will work with default settings but user can create his config file to override those settings. the question is: what is a standard location of such file on windows?

on linux it's: `~/.mylib/*` or `~/.config/mylib/*`

regarding windows i found [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677388/default-location-for-configuration-files-macos) saying many different locations: `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, `%USERPROFILE%` or `%APPDATA%` and then `./mylib/*`. i also found [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115116/1100135) introducing `$HOMEDRIVE` and `$HOMEPATH` variables.

so where should my lib expect user to store his config file?

Comment: Do you know about the system property `user.home`?

Comment: yep. but i don't know if user home is a standard location on windows. on linux for example a lot of apps store their configs not directly in user home but somewhere deeper. what's the standard on windows?

Answer (score 0):

`%APPDATA%/appname/configfile`

This is the standard location and it's used by most windows applications. [This blog post from msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions/) is the most authoritative source I could find.